# Jquery click with mouseup event issue

Tags: jquery, html

This is a code snippet that i have been using to all the buttons for the website to showcase a jump effect. These buttons can also have click event to execute some functions depending on functionality.

```
$("body").on("mousedown", ".btn", function () {
     $(this).css({
         "margin-top": "+=4px",
         "padding-bottom": "-=4px"
     });
 });

 $("body").on("mouseup", ".btn", function () {
     $(this).css({
         "margin-top": "-=4px",
         "padding-bottom": "+=4px"
     });
 });
```

The issue in that in chrome and safari sometimes the click event won't work but button mousedown and up are working fine. Is the click event cancelled by mouse up in chrome and safari ?

And this problem only occurs occasionally? 
What may be the issue ?

Comment: I didn't get issues related to click event in chrome, see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chennanfei/tjeeL/)

Comment: The `mouseup` event simultaneously runs with the `click` event.